# dynamically adding removeCaller function in js

Tags: javascript

why doesn't my javascript function work?

```
function removeCaller(param) {
    this.parentNode.removeChid(this);
}

caller = document.getElementById("a");
param = document.getElementById("b");
caller.removeCaller(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to do doesnt make sense. You dont even attach removerCaller to caller , how could it work ? furthermore , you declare a param argument in your function but never use it. it's not going to work that way. an element cannot be a child of itself , therefore you cannot remove "this" as a child of "this" or ?!? ...

if b is a child of a  , and a and b are ids , then just do

```
a.removeChild(b)
```

Comment: so how would you go about making the removeCaller function such that the caller (i.e., dom element who calls this function) would be removed?